# Delete key value pair in firestore field?

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

How can I delete a key:value inside of a field in firestore.

Here is the sample structure.

[image: Firestore]

```
 void rejectReq(String name) {
      final us = _firestore
          .collection("users")
          .doc(_auth.currentUser!.email); //index person
      us.update({
        "requests": FieldValue.delete()
      });
  }
```

This code deletes field "requests" but I want to delete key value pair inside "requests".

Suppose I delete a@a.com from "requests"

So now "requests" should be like

```
requests 
    e@e.com : 5
```

Here "name" is the parameter i.e key I want to delete.

Comment: Does `.child(key).remove()` work?

Comment: Your contradicting yourself: do you want to remove the entire key/value or do you only want to remove a value?

Comment: @MendelG where should I write it? After delete() ?

Comment: @MendelG both key and value.

Comment: LIke this `_firestore.collection("users")doc(_auth.currentUser!.email).doc(key).remove()`

Comment: @MendelG  .doc(name).remove() part giving error.

Answer (score 0):

> #### [Update elements in an array](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#dart_11)
>
> If your document contains an array field, you can use arrayUnion() and
> arrayRemove() to add and remove elements.
>
> ```
> washingtonRef.update({   "regions":
> FieldValue.arrayRemove(["east_coast"]), });
> ```